# how to disable a particular column using handsontable in handsontable

Tags: handsontable

How to disable a particular column using handsontable in handsontable.I want first column only editable other three columns get disable.I'm using readonly true for three columns but it's not work how to disable....

```
     columns: [
              {
     type:'handsontable',
     handsontable: {

      colHeaders: ['EmployeeNo','EmployeeName','Department','Designation'],
      data: manufacturerData,
      columns:[{},{readOnly: true},
          {
         readOnly: true
            },
          {
        readOnly: true
          }]
         }

         },
         {}]
```

Answer (score 3):

In Project i do it with this line of codes.

```
 cells : function(row, col, prop) {
                var cellProperties = {};

                if (col > 0) {
                    cellProperties.readOnly = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    cellProperties.readOnly = false;
                }

                return cellProperties;
            }
```

You can find working example of it on given link. but give example is for set a row to readonly.  http://handsontable.com/demo/conditional.html

Answer (score 3):

Your code is working properly. Please see JSFiddle with approach similar to you.

```
$("#test").handsontable({
    startRows: 1,
    startCols: 1,
    rowHeaders: true,
    colHeaders: true,
    minSpareCols: 0,
    minSpareRows: 0,
    contextMenu: false,
    fillHandle: false,
    outsideClickDeselects: false,
    removeRowPlugin: false,
    currentRowClassName: 'currentRow',
    currentColClassName: 'currentCol',
    columnSorting: true,
    colHeaders: ['Col1','Col2','Col3','Col4'],
    columns: [{},
              {readOnly: true}, 
              {readOnly: true},
              {readOnly: true}]
  });
```

Working link : http://jsfiddle.net/rvd61fuy/

Let me know, if you are facing anyother issue.

Answer (score 0):

To disable you could make the cell/column readonly and maybe even set the background color to a grey(to give a special effect).Both the methods i.e the one where you use readonly:true in the column declaration  when initializing the handsontable and also the one where you use cell properties and use conditions to determine if you need to set a cell to read only when the table is being rendered,both methods seem to be working for me.You need to instantiate your HOT correctly, that may be the problem. Also when using cell properties you needn't use cellProperties.readOnly = false as by default the cells are not read only unless you have coded for that seperately. If you need further assistance let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Also check that you have the latest version of handsontable. I ran into problems trying to implement readonly on cells which had checkbox columns with erratic results.

Using the version below solved my issues (below is what I used in my HTML page)

```
<script src="http://docs.handsontable.com/pro/1.9.0/bower_components/handsontable-pro/dist/handsontable.full.min.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://docs.handsontable.com/pro/1.9.0/bower_components/handsontable-pro/dist/handsontable.full.min.css">
```